# Apple Books Can't Access Your Library

Tags: books

When starting the Books app I get the following error message:

````
Apple Books Can't Access Your Library

Make sure the disk containing your library is connected, then click Try Again.

Library Location: (null)

You can also reset your library, then sign in to view and re-download your purchased books.```

How can I reset the location? Clicking on "Reset Location" does nothing.
I found the library with the books still there, but there is no way to set the location.

Running Mojave 10.14.6
````

Comment: Where is located your Books Library? The righ location is ```~/Library/Containers/com.apple.BKAgentService/Data/Documents/iBooks/Books```

Comment: I know where it is. The program does not give an opportunity to set the location. Clicking "resetting" does nothing.